# Could not load file Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, sharepoint, json.net

I am developing a Ribbon control and I want to use JSON.NET. I'm having this error :

Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried a couple of things, that I found here in stackoverflow such as:

- reinstall JSON.NET, with nuget console;
- Open up packages.config
- Delete the Newtonsoft.Json entry.
- Save and Build Re-add Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet.
- Build and run
- checked files on bin folder

nothing seems to work, any ideias?

Comment: Is the `CopyLocal` setting, set to true?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have 4.5.0.0 version of JSON.NET? Then try changing x86 to any CPU in build config of your solution

Comment: actually on web.config file I have the version 5.0.6, why does the error says 4.5.0.0? And yes CopyLocal is set to true

Comment: Check out the answers to this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776090/newtonsoft-json-assembly-conflict/21639708#21639708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my solution:

- Right-click on the "references" of your project.
- Add a referencec
- In the framework tab, type "json.net". I had two versions: 4.5 and 6.0. I only checked 4.5 and left the 6.0 unchecked.
- Rebuild and relaunch the project, and this error disappeared for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do any of the other projects in the same solution also reference Json.Net?
It may be that different projects in the same solution refer to different version of Json.Net.

Comment: This is the only project on this solution. It's the first time that I'm using(trying) JSON.net