# How to solve the Newtonsoft.Json confilict in vs2015

Tags: c#, json.net, visual-studio-2015, akka.net

I try to build the [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/docs/Building%20and%20Distributing%20Akka) as `build all`  ,but there is a error:

> CS0433: Configuration\Hocon\HoconObject.cs(47,10): The type 'JsonIgnoreAttribute' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

I don't know why the vs2015 will to find the **'Newtonsoft.Json'** in foler `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\` not the reference path `..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

[Here](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Akka.csproj) is the akka.net project file `Akka.csproj`.

Please help me to solve the problem.Thanks

--------------------Update---------------

I found the `Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll` as follow:
[image]

Is there a problem in Nuget now?

Comment: Have you try Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json ?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution and after rebuild it? this iften Restore the Nuget-Packages. If not, Enter on Manage Nuget Packages and update it manually.

Comment: @dachibox Akka.NET has solve the problem in the latest source code.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar kind of error once and Solved this by renaming the Dll and adding it to reference.

The other way around is you copy the DLL version to the bin of the project and then add it to reference.

Each time you are building as you referred, visual studio is downloading the latest package and hence this conflict arises.

I would suggest you to go for the second approach.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: @S Anil Kumar Dora I found the dll fetched by nuget is not right,now.I have updated the question,Please check it.

Comment: hello @huoxudong125,

Did you try with putting the dll in bin folder.

Are you using the DLL from nuget directly.

Comment: Please refer the below link it may help you solve this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776090/newtonsoft-json-assembly-conflict

Comment: @S yes I fetch the dll from nuget directly by the command `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -7.0.1`

Comment: Please change your web.config and try.

Above I have shared a link. Please go through it.

Comment: Thanks ,I edit the project to change the `NewtonSoft.Josn` all path in <choose> setction.after I changed the path as the nuget package folder, the errors gone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what fixed it for me:
Delete bin and obj folders,
Uninstall-Package Akka, then 
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json to latest version (8.0+)
Then, Install-Package Akka, 
which will pick up the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json and be happy :).