# Visual Studio 2010: Newtonsoft.Json error

Tags: visual-studio, json.net

I new in MVC4 and try to create simple web site. But whenever I am creating new project in mvc using Internet application, it gave me error:

**not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference**

I have tried to update the **Newtonsoft.Json'** using command **Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json**. But its not working.

Ref: **[Newtonsoft.Json Assembly Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776090/newtonsoft-json-assembly-conflict)**

Please help me, what I am missing.

Comment: Have you checked that the package is actually in your references?

Comment: Yes! Whenever we create new project it will add it by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming the Newtonsoft.Json.dll from below locations and rebuild your project.

Visual studio actually looks for Newtonsoft.Json.dll from below locations by default.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\ToolsRef

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0\lib

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend