# The type initializer for 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have added a new Web API project. I install Cors

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Pre
```

Then when I run my project, I get this error:

> The type initializer for 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' threw
>   an exception.

This is my inner exception:

> {"Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration..cctor()' to
>   access field
>   'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2'
>   failed."}

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I came across the same issue and found a blog post on it. According to this blog post if you use the release candidate it should fix the error

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -IncludePrerelease
```

From here: http://wp.sjkp.dk/webapi-and-cors-enabled-rest-services/

This worked for me :D

In other words, it was fixed in `5.1.0-rc1` release.

Comment: I am getting exact same error, though I am using final release version of all packages (as MVC5 is finally released).

Comment: I had the same problem with an MVC4 project. Installing the latest version of WebApi appears to have fixed it.

Comment: I got this error while trying to create a SPA from the HotTowel template in Visual Studio. This solved my issue, thank you!

Comment: I have problems with 5.2.2

Comment: @IsaacLlopis I just tried with 5.2.2 and it worked for me. this was using a blank MVC project in .net 4.5. what's the issue you are getting?

Comment: I was getting exactly the one above. I ended up having to remove all references from NuGet and adding them again. When I removed the references from NuGet I looked into the Web.Config and I saw there were version redirects for some of the DLLs still there, so I removed them too. Then Nuget added it all plainly from scratch and it was OK.

Comment: This is still a viable solution after 2 years.

Comment: Anyway to do the equivalent of `IncludePrerelease` to the Manage NuGet Packages UI (instead of doing Adween's technique in the console?)

Comment: Can do `Update-Package` command if already installed: `PM> Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -IncludePrerelease
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi' from version '5.0.0' to '5.2.3' in project 'xml2SqlWebApp'.`

Answer (score 50):

I had this problem using NET 4.6.1 and after may hours of research removing this from web.config finally fixed the issue:

```
<runtime>
<dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

Comment: I had the same issue in .NET 4.7.2 with version 4.2.0.0, so this seems to be a consistent issue.

Comment: I had this issue after adding ApplicationInsights to an older VB.net application.

Comment: Persistent issue with .Net 4.8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Definitely "Cors" doesn't work to me!

What I did to solve my problem with Cross Domain in WebApi it was remove Cors and change my web.config

If you insert the following lines inside your web.config, you'll have an WebApi with Cross Domain enabled.

`<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Definitely the simplest solution.