# Asp.net MVC4 Website hosting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, json.net

I have developed a asp.net mvc4 website using VS2010 and it is running perfectly fine after publishing and hosting it to the same developer machine.

then i hosted the same on to the testing system which has only .net framework(4.5.1) and asp.net mvc4 run time installed, then it is giving a run time exception stating that

`Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

i checked all my references in my project but there is no `Newtonsoft.Json` referenced. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please refer the screenshot [image]

Comment: make sure on the production copy or in the published solution in bin folder NewtowSoft.dll is there, it is not able to find dll in bin

Comment: There's a nice [thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027543/visual-studio-2012-web-api-project-wont-run-cant-find-newtonsoft-json). Possible duplicate?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It is working with out newtonSoft.dll in bin directory in developer machinde, one more thing is i haven't referenced this dll in my project

Comment: but it will not work on production server @vallabha

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Can you tell me the reason please

Comment: because the error says that it is not found in bin folder

Comment: locally you may have included the dll but make it is copy to local set to true else it will not be added in the publish

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i checked my references, in VS2010 there is no Newtonsoft.json.dll added

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your web.config you have lines like

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

remove those that give errors like the json in this case and update that package from nuget :)

Comment: thanks for the reply...but there is no newtonsoft.json reference in web.config file